# How to reliably block all incoming connections in Windows 10 Firewall?

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall

In Windows 10 "Firewall and Advances Security" **I want to block all Incoming network connections. Forever.**

The initial setup is easy:

- Block incoming connection setting (already set by default)
- Manually disable / delete all Inbound Rules

But the problem is, that after some time there are many new Rules added. Some are added by Windows (I believe it asks to allow program through firewall).

**But there are many that are added without asking user permission.** For example: "@$(runtime.ProgramFiles)\Hyper-V\SnapInAbout.dll,-212"

[image]

So the question is - **How to reliably block all incoming connections?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Defender and click on `Firewall and network protection` you will find separate settings for private and public networks with the same options, including one at the bottom to block all incoming connections, regardless of application permissions.

[image]

I can't easily test this, but it appears to do what you want. You will need to set it separately for both network classes.